# SQL complaining about an existing field

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

The following query attempts to do what can be expressed as `@users.courses` (where @user.id = 1). I'm giving this information as I'm not exactly sure if this is right since the query doesn't run

```
SELECT * FROM courses WHERE courses.id = 
 courses_users.user_id AND courses_users.user_id = 1
```

SQL complains:

> #1054 - Unknown column 'courses_users.user_id' in 'where clause'

I am certain that all of these fields exist so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `where` clause references `courses_users`, but this tables never appears in a `where` or `join` clause.

You should either added it to the `from` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   courses, courses_users -- Here!
WHERE  courses.id = courses_users.user_id AND 
       courses_users.user_id = 1
```

Or, better yet, use an explicit `join` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   courses
JOIN   courses_users ON courses.id = courses_users.user_id -- Here!
WHERE  courses_users.user_id = 1
```

Comment: If i find the query without `JOIN` easier to understand is it a problem? Is it considered `bad code` ?

Comment: Implicit joins (the first example) are considered deprecated in most RDBMSs. They aren't strictly prohibited, but it's generally considered a bad practice to keep on using them.

Comment: Also I just discovered that to achieve what i described using rails syntax  the second line must be replaced with `courses.id = courses_users.course_id`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `JOIN`. The statement doesn't know about `courses_users` unless you `JOIN` to it. For this your query needs to look something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM courses 
JOIN courses_users ON
    courses.id = courses_users.user_id 
WHERE 
    courses_users.user_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you attempting to show only the records where courses.id match a different value in a different table? If so, you need to join the two tables together. You can't compare two different fields from two different tables without a join.

Here's a tutorial on how SQL joins work: [SQL Joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)